# Set TextView inside CardView without resizing views

Tags: android, textview, cardview

I am working on a settings page for an app where users would need to set text sizes based on their preference. Am previewing a chunk of sample text inside a `cardView` so they can see and apply their changes. 
My issue is that as the text increases or decreases, the card view adjusts itself. How do i prevent the `cardView` from pushing other views when the text is changed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previewText"
            android:text="My Text"
            android:fontFamily="@font/muli_bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="29sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/customTextColor"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     //other views here
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Give the constant height value?

Comment: yeah. such that other views are not affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the issue correctly, you just need to set a constant height for the card like this: `android:layout_height="200dp"`. 
So, no matter how big the text inside is, the card will remain the same, but the text will be cut off.

Here's a full CardView code:

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/previewView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/previewText"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:fontFamily="@font/muli_bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="29sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/customTextColor"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Hope it'll resolve your issue.